# How to use classes defined in the library referenced by a class library which is referenced in my app?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, c#-3.0

Is there a way I can access the classes of a library which is referenced by another library and which I am using in my app?

In short ->

```
Library A   | Library B            | App C
 - Class A  |  - Class B           |  - Class C
            |  - references lib A  |  - references lib B
            |                      |  ( Can I access class A here without explicitly 
            |                      |    referencing lib A since it is already referenced 
            |                      |    through lib B )
```

Comment: What have you tried? What errors did you get?

Comment: If you don't reference `Library A` in `App C` the compiler can't figure out what `Class A` is. It does not matter that `Lib A` is referenced in another project. So the answer is **no**. However, it is more interesting to learn _why_ you need this. The versioning issues that you mentioned in another comment, what are they? You should ask how to handle them.

Comment: Well, yes, the primary thing I am trying to resolve are versioning issues. So, if version of `Library A` are upgraded and `Library B` decides to upgrade their referenced version of `Library A` to a newer version, then my app also needs to upgrade the version of `Library A` to whatever version `Library B` is using. That's pain in the ass.
Instead it would have been better to just use whatever version of `Library A` is implicitly available to the `App`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless Library B provides the interface to `references lib A` externally,
Otherwise, Library A cannot be accessed through Library B.

If Library B is C# Lib and `references lib A` is a field in Library B, then you can try to use reflection.

Comment: This is incorrect. You don't need an interface from library B to library A. If you create a console app with 2 library projects and create the dependency tree that the OP showed then the console app can add objects in library A without adding a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using NuGet it will depend how the package has been created and the [assemblies are referenced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/create-packages/select-assemblies-referenced-by-projects);

> Explicit assembly references allows a subset of assemblies to be used for IntelliSense and compiling, while all assemblies are available at run-time.

If the assembly for `Library A` is packaged correctly your project may already include it as a reference and a `using` statement would be enough to access the classes in code.

Including a PackageReference to `Library A` in your project would make it more explicit and since it is declared as a dependency for `Library B` it would probably already be available in the `packages` directory. There may be versioning issues though if you subsequently update the package references.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, currently we have the `Library A` dependency mentioned explicitly in our app, but there usually are versioning issues and that's what I am trying to avoid.
Removing the explicit dependency causes App to not find any of the classes in `Library A`.

Comment: I have had this sort of problem as well and have only been able to manually manage the version conflicts. It meant always updating `Library B` first and only ever updating `Library A` to the same version referenced by `Library B`. I have considered creating our own internal NuGet package so at least then it can be controlled from a single place but we don't update that often for it to be enough of an issue.